# Better launch first a die given these conditions?

Tags: probability

2 opponents gotta launch a standard die. The second launcher can't get the same score of the first player. The winner is the player who gets an higher score. Is there any advantage in launching first or second?

Comment: What does "The second launcher can't get the same score of the first player" mean? What if he *does* throw the same score? Does he get to throw again? Does he lose? Does the dice explode?

Comment: It's an online game. The second player can't get the same score. I think he has 1/5 probability of getting the other possible scores.

Comment: @TomDawn Ok. You shouldn't say "2 opponents gotta launch a standard die" then. That at the very least implies that the two throws are statistically independent, which they cannot be with a rule like that...

Comment: Then? is the answer below correct?

Comment: What do you think? The answers suggest that you write down all the possible combinations (there are 30 of them, so the task is quite manageable) and find the number of times the first player wins vs. the number of times the second player wins. If you get the same counts, the game is fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Assuming that if 1st player gets x, the 2nd player cant get x. There is no advantage in playing first or second.

If you write down the probabilities for each player to win if the 1st player gets 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, You shall find a symmetry in winning probabilities i.e.

$(0,1)$ for $1$

$(\frac{1}{5},\frac{4}{5})$ for 2

$(\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5})$ for 3

$(\frac{3}{5},\frac{2}{5})$ for 4

$(\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{5})$ for 5

$(0,1)$ for 6